# I am trying to run a program that will tell you how many times a letter is repeated in a string based on raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7, raw-input

```
dict = {}
raw_input('Please enter a string :')
letter = raw_input()
for letter in raw_input:
    if letter not in dict.keys():
        dict[letter] = 1
    else:
        dict[letter] += 1

print dict
```

My error:

```
line 9, in <module>
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Not really related to your question, but look up defaultdict. It is helpful for this kind of code. The answer to your question is already handled below. You want to iterate over the result of raw_input(), which is not what you did.

Comment: Well this question definitely shows very little of research done by author itself. Please show a little bit more of your own effort before actually posting questions like this and not just copy first error message you get. ( or at least copy your error message into google, helps 8 out of 10 times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

worked for me when i changed `for letter in raw_input:` to `for letter in raw_input():` and the input was "question" and output was "{'e': 1, 'i': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1, 'q': 1, 's': 1, 'u': 1, 't': 1}" , and also i think you can change the part of code inside the for loop to `dict[letter] = dict.get(letter,0) + 1` if you like.

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving this error because you are attempting to iterate through `raw_input`: `for letter in raw_input:`.

However, in Python, only objects with an `__iter__()` method are iterable, and `raw_input` doesn't have this method (it's also a builtin in Python).  You can look up the type of an object using `type()` and a list of an object's methods using `dir()`:

```
>>> print type(raw_input)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>

>>> print dir(raw_input)
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__text_signature__']
```

You want to iterate through the *result* of `raw_input()` instead.  Here are some ways that your code should be improved:

- Either assign the result of `raw_input()` to a variable (for example: `letters = raw_input('Please enter a string :')`) or iterate through `raw_input('Please enter a string :')` directly.
- Use a variable name other than `dict` for your dictionary.  `dict` already exists as a builtin itself.
- Use proper indentation in your `for` and conditional `if` blocks.

End result:

```
dic = {}
letters = raw_input('Please enter a string :')
for letter in letters:
    if letter not in dic.keys():
        dic[letter] = 1
    else:
        dic[letter] += 1

print dic

# output:
# Please enter a string :success
# {'e': 1, 's': 3, 'c': 2, 'u': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way to do this is to use the `Counter` class in the built-in `collections` module:

```
from collections import Counter

print Counter(raw_input('Please enter a string: '))
```

A `Counter` can be accessed just like a dictionary:

```
>>> a = Counter('spam spam spam')
>>> print a
Counter({'a': 3, 'p': 3, 's': 3, 'm': 3, ' ': 2})
>>> print a['s']
3
```